# Cross-subscription Private Endpoint in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to use a Private endpoint between two services -

- In different VNETs
- VNETs are in different subscriptions and VNETs have not peered
- Subscriptions are in different Tenant

On similar lines, it seems, Private Link could also support the same - [Support for across VNET sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview#key-benefits:%7E:text=Privately%20access%20services%20on%20the%20Azure,services%20over%20the%20Azure%20backbone%20network.). Extract below -

"
Privately access services on the Azure platform: Connect your virtual network to services in Azure without a public IP address at the source or destination. Service providers can render their services in their own virtual network and consumers can access those services in their local virtual network. The Private Link platform will handle the connectivity between the consumer and services over the Azure backbone network"

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I don't think it's possible without VNet peered.

After my validation, we can access the service in different subscriptions and different tenants with private endpoint and [VNet to VNet peering enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions#powershell) in each VNet.

In subA and TenantA, I created

- VNetA and one Azure VMa without public IP deployed in that VNet. We can access the VM  with a bastion host in that VNet. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal#create-a-virtual-network-and-bastion-host).

In subB and TenantB, I create

- a storage account and a private DNS zone `privatelink.file.core.windows.net` and a VNetB.
- Enable the private endpoint for this storage account and storage subresource `file`, you may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal#create-storage-account-with-a-private-endpoint)

Note, we should link the VNetA and VNetB in the same private DNS zone, then we can get the file share FQDN resolved to the private IP address from the Azure VMa. Also, we should use an account having enough permission on both subscriptions.

[image]

If without the VNet peering, the network connecting is blocked because the VNet A and VNet B belong to different isolation virtual networks and there is no routing from VNet A and VNet B.

[image]

If the VNet peering at each other, the network connecting is successful.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive view of this. Let me also try it out and I will mark it as an answer!

Comment: So, I am not sure whether I am missing something. With or without peering I am getting the public IP for the blob storage endpoint. On the source VNet, I get the correct IP, an internal one, but on the consumer VNet, the VM resolves the IP to a public one. Why would that be? I would expect a private IP with peered n/w.

Comment: Do you have both vnets linked to the same private dns zone？

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks, this was a great answer. I have marked the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible, works Private Endpoints works just fine across subscriptions and tenants. You just need to create them slightly differently. Create them from the destination side, then on the Resource page select "Connect to an Azure resource by resource ID or alias.". And paste the resource id you are connecting to. Resource ID can be obtained on the resource overview page - JSon link.
One it's done - go to the source->private endpoints and manually approve requested private endpoint.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When selecting `Connect to an Azure resource by resource ID or alias`, what's not very clear are the actual values for `Resource ID or alias`(2) and `Target sub-resource`(3).

[image]

In this example, I am referencing a storage account and file share.

`Resource ID or alias` = Resource ID of the storage account. e.g:

```
/subscriptions/aaaaa-1111-11111-aaaa-asasdas212/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystorageaccount
```

`Target sub-resource` is the name of the sub-resource from the following list:
[image]
*Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#dns-changes-for-private-endpoints*